# Using Javascript cookies in Java

Tags: java, javascript

can I access cookies added in Javascript in my java servlet??

in my javascript I've done,

```
var mydata = ace.edit("editor").getValue();
document.cookie="data="+mydata;
```

how can I access this in my java servlet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
  String name = cookies[i].getName();
  String value = cookies[i].getValue();
}
```

try this in servlet.

Comment: But I didnt give any name for the cookie in my `js`??

Comment: check the name of cookie in jquery. It must has some reference.

Comment: Your question states that your cookie name is `data`. You can find it server side by checking for `name.equals("data")` in above code.

Comment: IT says there is no cookie by the name `data`